# How do I count capitals as abbreviations from a text file

Tags: java, drjava

So my program is supposed to read a text file which contains tweet post (one tweet per line). It should output the number of hashtags (any word beginning with #) and name tags (any word beginning with @), and the difficult part: it should check for appreviations (words in all caps that do not begin with @ or #); then print the abbreviations alongside how many they are. For example;
Input is

```
OMG roommate @bob drank all the beer...#FML #ihatemondays
lost TV remote before superbowl #FML
Think @bieber is soo hawt...#marryme
seeing @linkinpark & @tswift in 2 weeks...OMG
```

Output should look like this:

```
Analyzing post:
OMG roommate @bob drank all the beer...#FML #ihatemondays
Hash tag count: 2
Name tag count: 1
Acronyms: OMG 
For a total of 1 acronym(s).
```

This is my code:

```
import java.io.*; //defines FileNotFoundException
import java.util.Scanner; // import Scanner class

    public class TweetAnalyzer {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    //variables
        String tweet;
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("A3Q1-input.txt"));

        while (inputFile.hasNextLine())
        {
          tweet = inputFile.nextLine();
          System.out.println("Analyzing post: ");
          System.out.println("\t" + tweet);
          analyzeTweet(tweet);
        }


      }//close main 

      public static void analyzeTweet(String tweet){
        int hashtags = countCharacters(tweet, '#');
        int nametags = countCharacters(tweet, '@');
        System.out.println("Hash tag: " + hashtags);
        System.out.println("Name tag: " + nametags);
        Acronyms(tweet);

      }//close analyzeTweet

      public static int countCharacters(String tweet, char c)//char c represents both @ and # symbols
      {
        int characters = 0;
        char current;
        for(int i=0;i<tweet.length();i++)
        {
          current = tweet.charAt(i);
          if(current == c)
          {
            characters++;
          }
        }
        return characters;
      }

      public static boolean symbol(String tweet, int i) {
        boolean result = true;
        char c;
        if(i-1 >=0)
        {
          c = tweet.charAt(i - 1);
          if (c == '@' || c == '#') {
            result = false;
        }
        }//close if
        else
        {
         result = false;
        }
        return result;
      }

      public static void Acronyms (String tweet){
        char current;
        int capital = 0;
        int j = 0;
        String initials = "";


        for(int i = 0; i < tweet.length(); i++) {
          current = tweet.charAt(i);
          if(symbol(tweet, i) && current >= 'A' && current <= 'Z') {       
            initials += current;
            j = i + 1; 
            current = tweet.charAt(j);
            while(j < tweet.length() && current >= 'A' && current <= 'Z') {
              current = tweet.charAt(j);
              initials += current;
              j++;

            }
            capital++;
            i = j;
            initials += " ";
            }
          else {

            j = i + 1; 
            current = tweet.charAt(j);
            while(j < tweet.length() && current >= 'A' && current <= 'Z') {
              current = tweet.charAt(j);

              j++;

            }

            i = j;

        }
        }
         System.out.println(initials);
         System.out.println("For a total of " + capital + " acronym(s)");
    }//close Acronyms


      }//TweetAnalyzer
```

everything works except the abbreviations part. 
This is my output:

```
Analyzing post: 
    OMG roommate @bob drank all the beer...#FML #ihatemondays
Hash tag: 2
Name tag: 1

For a total of 0 acronym(s)
Analyzing post: 
    lost TV remote before superbowl #FML
Hash tag: 1
Name tag: 0

For a total of 0 acronym(s)
Analyzing post: 
    Think @bieber is soo hawt...#marryme
Hash tag: 1
Name tag: 1

For a total of 0 acronym(s)
Analyzing post: 
    seeing @linkinpark & @tswift in 2 weeks...OMG
Hash tag: 0
Name tag: 2
OMG 
For a total of 1 acronym(s)
```

please I need help fixing the abbreviation part. thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems more natural to go through word by word like this:

```
for (String word : tweet.split("\\s+")) {
    if (word.charAt(0) == '@') {
        names++;

    } else if (word.charAt(0) == '#') {
        hashtags++;

    } else if (word.toUpperCase().equals(word)) {
        abbrevs++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can there be other whitespace besides space?

Comment: @tieTYT True.. Edited to allow for regex whitespace matching

Comment: names, hashtags, abbrevs are what variables? chars or strings or int?

Comment: @user2932716 They are ints. It's just a way to count how many of each you have. You should initialize them to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do:  I'd split the tweet on whitespace so you have a list of words.  Then I'd throw out the words that contain symbols.  You can use [StringUtils.isAlpha](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isAlpha%28java.lang.String%29) for that.  Now, just check that `word.toUpperCase().equals(word)`.  If it does, that's an upper case word without symbols.  What you're calling an acronym.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method to get acronyms count:

```
private static int countAcronyms(String tweet) {
    int acronyms = 0;
    String[] words = tweet.split(" ");

    for (String word : words) {
        if(word.matches("[A-Z]+"))
            acronyms++;
    }

    return acronyms;
}
```

Comment: this works in counting the acronyms, thank you. But then, it doesn't count the last line in the input because there is a period before "OMG".
secondly, how do I print out the abbreviations counted by the countAcronyms method with a space in-between each one?

Comment: Try to change regexp in split method to properly split the string to words.

Comment: And to print acronym list declare an array or list variable and store given words in it. Make method to return this list. Now you'll be able to print each element as long as count them:-)

Comment: private static List<String> getAcronyms(String tweet) {
    int acronyms = 0;
    String[] words = tweet.split(" ");
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String word : words) {
        if(word.matches("[A-Z]+"))
            result.add(word);
    }

    return result;}

Comment: Sorry for junk comment. I wrote it from my phone :-)

Comment: please can u post it as an answer? Because it is giving me errors. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `StringTokenizer` to split white spaces something like this

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer (yourString);
while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
   String str = st.nextElement();
   if(str.toUpperCase().equals(str)) {
      abbrvCount++;
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.